# Icon over the button of v-switch vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using vuetify
and I just wanna add an icon over the button of v-switch,
I searched in slots and found nothing

`<v-switch  label="Dark mode" flat inset></v-switch>`

I wanna do like this picture

[image]

Comment: What happens when you put an Icon right before the `<v-switch>`? How is this different from what you need?

Comment: I have added this picture to clarify

Comment: You mean something like this: https://codepen.io/incyclum/pen/MqXmzo

Comment: Sorry, you can't add an icon to v-switch vuetify component :(

Answer (score 2):

You can use v-checkbox, with off-icon and on-icon.
As  example:

```
<v-checkbox class="pt-3"
    v-model="$vuetify.theme.dark"
    color="purple"
    off-icon="mdi-theme-light-dark"
    on-icon="mdi-theme-light-dark"
  ></v-checkbox>
```

Reference at https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-checkbox/#props

Answer (score 1):

far you can do is `append-icon` and/or `prepend-icon` props

you can check the detail at https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-switch/#props